# How to add filter button to ui-grid header

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-ui-grid

how can get a filtering enable/disable button inside the grid's header.

I have this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MrdEiOVhykq346dZ7Esw?p=preview) where you can see the enable/disable filtering option but I need it inside the grids header like in the bellow picture.

bassically I need this button:

```
<button id='toggleFiltering' ng-click="toggleFiltering()" class="btn btn-success">Filter</button>
```

in the grid's header

[image]

Comment: you want a button in your header right

Comment: yes, that is what I want

Comment: if its related to the source column, you can add filterHeaderTemplate on the column definition, and define it there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it :)

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UwecfSOIum6uCZKJSSYr?p=preview)

here is the main part under columnDefs:

```
      {field: 'filtertoggle', displayName: '', visible: true,  headerCellTemplate: '' +
                            '<button id=\'toggleFiltering\' ng-click="grid.appScope.toggleFiltering()" class="btn btn-success">' +
                            'Toggle Filtering</button>'
      }
```

and the called function is directly in the scope object:

```
  $scope.toggleFiltering = function(){
      $scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = !$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering;
      $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
  };
```

Comment: Practically I added another column to the table and since this button  has a small width was just fine like that